# an regex to filter the html

Tags: c#, html, regex, filter

I want get a regex to filter the html. The rule is: remove all the tags from the html string except `li` tags (if there is content in the `li`).

What's the right regex?

Source string:

```
<td>1</td><li>2</li><li></li>
```

Expected result:

```
1<li>2</li>
```

Comment: Confused...What's the html code?

Comment: Edited so the code was visible. In general the correct answer is use the right tool for the job. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: Does your language of choice not have an HTML parser?

Comment: Your example "source html" has no `<pre>` tags in it, so it's unclear what you mean. In any case, the general answer to "I want get an Regex to filter the html" is "don't use a regex to filter HTML. Use an HTML parser." You don't say what language you're programming in, but chances are that its got at least on HTML parsing library.

Comment: @TrueWill +1 for linking to something besides that "all is lost" answer which I used to think was funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going with C# the Regex looks a little like this:

```
@"(?<=\<li.*\>)(.*?)(?=\</li\>)"
```

Answer (score 0):

some ugly way to do it:

```
$html = 'SOME HTML CODE';
$html = str_replace('<li></li>', '', $html);
$html = str_replace('<li>', '__LI_START__', $html);
$html = str_replace('</li>', '__LI_END__', $html);
$html = strip_tags($html);
$html = str_replace('__LI_START__', '<li>', $html);
$html = str_replace('__LI_END__', '</li>', $html);
```

if i understood correctly, it will do the job (although it's ugly, regex or some XML tools are nicer options).

Answer (score 0):

may I know what programming language you are working on?
for example in python

```
import re
html = '<td>1</td><li>2</li><li></li>'

//Replacing the content of the tags by variable
html = re.sub('<((?!li).)+>(?P<var>[^<>]*)</((?!li).)+>', '\g<var>', html)  
//Cleaning the blank li
html = re.sub('<li>\\s*</li>', '', html)
print html
>> 1<li>2</li>



<((?!li).)+> means all tags except <li> tag
```